# Delphi 2009 SOAP request does not transfer user name with Windows Vista

Tags: delphi, soap, windows-vista, delphi-2009, vista64

We implemented a small application that uses the SOAP interface from Mantis Bugtracker (http://mantisbt.sf.net/). Mantis is installed on an SSL webserver that requires HTTP authentication.

It works perfectly in Windows XP, but not on 64-bit Vista, where it fails with "Access denied". Looking into the server's access log, I can see that it gets Error 401 unauthorized, and no username seems to be transferred to the webserver.

In other words, it seems that the SOAP request does not include the username, if it is run on Windows Vista 64-bit, whereas on Windows XP, everything works perfectly.

Does anybody have an idea what this could be?

Comment: What components are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is much too little information here to be able to tell anything, but I'll venture an educated guess - it's a permission issue. When obtaining the local username you're doing something that requires Administrator access - and under Vista you're by default running as a limited user.

Try running the app by right clicking it and choosing Run as Administrator. If it works then, you've confirmed that suspicion.

How exactly are you querying the credentials which you want to send over the network?

Edit: Never mind, it was a different issue altogether :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the ideas. I don't know why comment sizes are limited here, so the short report: It is actually a 2-phase login, and one of the passwords needed to go into the preferences, where it was absent. The conclusion is: Vista does not run this application different than Windows XP.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out then :)